# How to get the value of $\alpha$ in contractive condition,here its $\frac14$.How?

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $x_1=1$ and $x_{n+1}=\dfrac 1{2+x_n}$. Then $$\left|x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}\right|=\frac{1}{(2+x{n+1})(2+x_n)}\left|x_n-x_{n+1}\right|<\frac 14 \left|x_n-x_{n+1}\right|$$ Therefore $(x_n)$ satisfies the contractive condition with $\alpha=\frac 14$...

How to get value of $\alpha$ here it is $\frac 14$?

Comment: Hint: if $x \gt 0$ then $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2+x} \lt \frac{1}{2}\,$.

Comment: Did not get it sorry.

Comment: You have that $x_n \gt 0$ (by induction, for example). Then $\frac{1}{(2+x_{n+1})(2+x_{n})} \lt \frac{1}{2 \,\cdot\, 2} = \frac{1}{4}\,$.

Comment: This question does not make sense. You first have to state a problem that contains the unknown $\alpha$, then you can present us $\alpha=\frac 14$ as the solution of the problem and ask us why $\alpha$ is the solution. So please state the problem where $\alpha$ is the unknown.

Comment: The question was that given a sequence with elements,we need to show that it satisfy cauchy criteria or not.The elements are mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that in your example, since the first member of the sequence, $x_{1}$, is non-negative, every subsequent member will also be non-negative since $x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2 + x_{n}}$ (if this was negative, the previous member, $x_{n}$ would have had to be negative, which it isn't).

Second, the constant in the contractive condition is not uniquely defined. All you have to do is find *some* $0 < \alpha < 1$ and you can apply the argument. So you just need to look for **one** possible $\alpha$, which in your example is given by $\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}$ since for $x > 0$, $\frac{1}{2+x} < \frac{1}{2}$, as pointed out by dxiv in the comments. It doesn't matter if there are for example "better" (i.e. smaller) alphas, finding one is enough for your purposes.

Hope that helps!

Andre

Comment: I thought that that α is not uniquely defined,as you mentioned only a possible value of α can used.But the logic helped me to clear the concept.   Thanks Andre!